# Kafka log4j log rotator is not rotating logs

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

I have this snippet in my log4j configuration file:

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

And in /var/log/kafka, indeed I see the server.log file. However, under my path /opt/kafka/logs, I see this below:

```
(server.log.2021-02-04-00 and continuing on...) 
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 08:57 server.log.2021-03-05-08
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 09:57 server.log.2021-03-05-09
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka    2361 Mar  5 10:57 server.log.2021-03-05-10
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 11:57 server.log.2021-03-05-11
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 12:57 server.log.2021-03-05-12
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 13:57 server.log.2021-03-05-13
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 14:57 server.log.2021-03-05-14
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 15:57 server.log.2021-03-05-15
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka     942 Mar  5 16:57 server.log.2021-03-05-16
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka    2361 Mar  5 17:57 server.log.2021-03-05-17
(all the way to server.log.2021-03-15-20)
```

How can I get these logs to delete properly? Why does it seem to make a log file per hour? Why would kafka be logging to another path?